# I'm new to JS, I would like to know how I can get specific information from HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am studying and learning JS, and I would like to select a specific element of HTML to use in some functions, example:

```
<a class="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/mathns_/" tabindex="0" style="width: 56px; height: 56px;"><img alt="Foto do perfil de mathns_" class="_6q-tv" data-testid="user-avatar" draggable="false" src="https://instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/65158471_584667738728022_8425647488723058688_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_ohc=XL5y1cJG98AAX8-AXnU&amp;oh=baec81bb4b516812d2302c2845bee070&amp;oe=5F821018"></a>
```

From the code above, I would just like to get the "href = / mathns _ /" ...

I tried to do the following:

```
document.querySelector('._2dbep.qNELH.kIKUG')
```

It even works, but it returns me the class of another feed (I'm using instagram as an example)

Could anyone help me? I would like to know if there is any way for me to select only the class and the information I really want!

When I run the document.querySelector it returns me from someone else:

```
<a class="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/southamericamemes/" tabindex="0" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"><img alt="Foto do perfil de southamericamemes" class="_6q-tv" data-testid="user-avatar" draggable="false" src="https://instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/117308071_215320116684944_6868475462134444917_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_ohc=utEb7fkGnskAX_8fyYS&amp;oh=cf0b439426a75d9c22049efa86093774&amp;oe=5F8245FD"></a>
```

Comment: Can you show some of the different "feeds", so we can see what the differences are? What distinguishes the `<a>` you want from the rest?

Comment: You could use `document.querySelectorAll` and find the "feed" that you need

Comment: Hi, do you want really want `href="/mathns_/"` or would you be interested in `/mathns_/` instead?

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns the *first* matching element. You'll have to find something unique about this element. Alternatively, you could select one of its children and use `.parentElement` one or more times to work your way up to the parent. Then, you can use `.getAttribute('href')` to get the `href`.

Comment: I edited the comment and left one more as an example @CertainPerformance

Comment: The problem is that someone else's information returns to me ... which I don't want. @matthew-e-brown

Comment: @MatheusNascimento Yes, exactly. Because you're selecting your element based on non-unique properties (their classes, which are meant to be generic in the first place), you're getting the first element in the order of the document that matches those classes. You will have to use something more precice than classes. If you're trying to **select** by the `href`, you can use the attribute selector (`a[href="/mathns_/"]`).

Comment: I would like to print only the HREF value, would it be possible?

Comment: @matthew-e-brown

Comment: Once you have selected the element, you can use either `element.href` or `element.getAttribute('href')` to get the HREF value.

Comment: But in this case I would like to get the href value with the document.querySelectorAll ...

Trying this way returns me undefined:

as = document.querySelectorAll('.sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5.ZIAjV').href
console.log(as) 

@matthew-e-brown

Comment: Because when you use `All`, you get an Array-like object. Use something like `[...document.querySelectorAll].map(el => el.href)` and you will get an array of `href`s.

Comment: I'm using it directly on the console and it tells me that .map is not a function ...

It looked like this:

as = document.querySelectorAll ('. sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5.ZIAjV'). map (el => el.href)

mistake:

document.querySelectorAll (...). map is not a function

Obs: Sorry for the persistence, I am studying and I want to learn more about it, before asking I look for solutions ... @matthew-e-brown

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` does not return an Array, but an array-like object. You must convert it to an array. Notice that I wrapped it with `[...  ]`. This is the modern-JS way, but you can also use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll()).map`. See here: [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [the `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `<a>` with the `href="/mathns_/"` instead by putting *that* into the selector:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('[href="/mathns_/"]');
console.log(a);
```

```html
<a class="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/southamericamemes/" tabindex="0" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"><img alt="Foto do perfil de southamericamemes" class="_6q-tv" data-testid="user-avatar" draggable="false" src="https://instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/117308071_215320116684944_6868475462134444917_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_ohc=utEb7fkGnskAX_8fyYS&amp;oh=cf0b439426a75d9c22049efa86093774&amp;oe=5F8245FD"></a>
<a class="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/mathns_/" tabindex="0" style="width: 56px; height: 56px;"><img alt="Foto do perfil de mathns_" class="_6q-tv" data-testid="user-avatar" draggable="false" src="https://instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/65158471_584667738728022_8425647488723058688_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcgh13-1.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_ohc=XL5y1cJG98AAX8-AXnU&amp;oh=baec81bb4b516812d2302c2845bee070&amp;oe=5F821018"></a>
```